# How to share a image from its url

Tags: android, eclipse

I am developing an android application and i need to share the image on button click.But i am getting Image URl only. So, how can i share the image???

And i am getting empty attachment if i give image URL to the intent.

my code is:

```
sharebut =(Button)findViewById(R.id.sharebut);
        sharebut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
         {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
         {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

            String screenshotUri = flag;
            sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image using"));

        }
    });
```

Comment: You can first store image in local and then share it with Intent.

Comment: Will the URI be always pointing to a local file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.. :)
Just created a file and share the content in imageview.

sharebut =(Button)findViewById(R.id.sharebut);
        sharebut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            imgflag.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap bmap = imgflag.getDrawingCache();
            OutputStream out = null;
            String path =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File file = new File(path, "test.png");
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
                out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
                 intent.setType("image/*");
                 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Your Image"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the path where your image is located in sd card in `Uri.parse("file:///"+ yourImagePath)`
Use :

```
 String path= "/Downloads/image1.jpg";  //Add your path here
 sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///"+ path));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this solution for share image via email from URL.

```
            String path = "";
            URL url;
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
            intent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm",
                    "com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, description);

                try {
                    url = new URL(thumnbnailURL);

                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                            .openConnection();

                    connection.setDoInput(true);

                    connection.connect();

                    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();

                    Bitmap immutableBpm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

                    Bitmap mutableBitmap = immutableBpm.copy(
                            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

                    View view = new View(VideoDetailsActivity.this);

                    view.draw(new Canvas(mutableBitmap));

                    path = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
                            mutableBitmap, "Nur", null);

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
                intent.setType("application/image");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);          


                startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: if i use this code i am getting error on "path = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
                            mutableBitmap, "Nur", null);" because i already having the class name called Images. What can I do now?

Comment: Above code Images comes under Media Store with this import file import android.provider.MediaStore.Images; Please rename your class name otherwise use proper import class